# Errors on every single classifier with my data in Python (Naives Bayes, Neural Network etc)

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, data-mining, naivebayes

I seem to get errors on every single classifier I use. I am using the Enron data (Enron 1 - 5) and trying to create a spam filter.

Lets take the Naïve Bayes as a example.

**How I get the data:**

```
# Collecting the ham/spam emails from the training set (environ 1, 3 and 5)
ham_training_location = os.listdir("Data/training(environ1,3,5)/ham")
spam_training_location = os.listdir("Data/training(environ1,3,5)/spam")
training_data = []

counter_three = 0;
start_timer = time.perf_counter()
for path_of_file in spam_training_location:
    if counter_three < 10:
        file_to_open = open("Data/training(environ1,3,5)/spam/" + path_of_file, "r", encoding="Latin-1")
        text = str(file_to_open.read())
        training_data.append([text, "spam"])

    counter_three = counter_three + 1

counter_four = 0
for path_of_file in ham_training_location:
    if counter_four < 10:
        file_to_open = open("Data/training(environ1,3,5)/ham/" + path_of_file, "r", encoding="Latin-1")
        file_text = str(file_to_open.read())
        training_data.append([file_text, "ham"])
    counter_four = counter_four + 1
```

I then repeat the above but with the testing set.

```
ham_testing_location = os.listdir("Data/testing(environ2,4)/ham")
spam_testing_location = os.listdir("Data/testing(environ2,4)/spam")
testing_data = []

counter_one = 0
for path_of_file in spam_testing_location:
    if counter_one < 10:
        file_to_open = open("Data/testing(environ2,4)/spam/" + path_of_file, "r", encoding="Latin-1")
        text = str(file_to_open.read())
        testing_data.append([text, "spam"])

    counter_one = counter_one + 1

counter_two = 0
for path_of_file in ham_testing_location:
    if counter_two < 10:
        file_to_open = open("Data/testing(environ2,4)/ham/" + path_of_file, "r", encoding="Latin-1")
        file_text = str(file_to_open.read())
        testing_data.append([file_text, "ham"])

    counter_two = counter_two + 1

print("Ham file (test) collection time in seconds: ", end_timer - start_timer)
```

I then convert them to numpy arrays:

```
training_data = np.array(training_data)
testing_data = np.array(testing_data)
```

**How I split the data and initialize the Naive Bayes classifier:**

```
# The below code splits the training and testing data up, so we now have the feature and label for each
x_train = training_data[:, 0]  # training feature
y_train = training_data[:, 1]  # training label
x_test = testing_data[:, 0]  # testing feature
y_test = testing_data[:, 1]  # testing label


gnb = GaussianNB()  # suitable for numeric features
gnb.fit(x_train, np.ravel(y_train, order='C'))
```

Last line above gives error:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

So I then listen to the advice and do the reshape:

```
x_train_nb = x_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train_nb = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
x_test_nb = x_test.reshape(-1, 1)
y_test_nb = y_test.reshape(-1, 1)
```

And then I get another error:

```
ValueError: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric'
```

**Other Classifiers:**

This happens with all the other classifiers I try and use. For example, if I use the same data but for a Nueral Network:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(1,)))
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(20,)))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible
```

Comment: Please do not include here `print` statements without their outcome, commented out code, or code that comes *after* the error, all of which just create unnecessary clutter; code here is supposed to be *minimal* (edited).

Answer (score 1):

What is your X_train data?...Is it a set of emails?...what is your y_train?...
Primarily you are not attempting to convert the text data into a numeric format.

Assuming x_train as set of emails which iin the format of text, you need to convert the text into vectors which the ML model understands.(use either count,TF-IDF vectorizers for simplicity)

Convert y_train(`ham` or `spam`) into a numerical format, i.e. map "ham" to zero and "spam" to one.

`ytrain = pd.Series(ytrain).map(lambda x : 0 if x=="ham" else 1)`

I don't know what Enron data is but I am giving a simple example of multiclass classification of the `20newsgroups dataset` that exists as a dataset in sklearn library.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import naive_bayes

data = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups()
email=data.data

# fit and transform the train the email text data to the tfidf vectorizer

tfidf=TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf.fit(email)
email_data = tfidf.transform(email)

# fit the transformed `email_data` to the naive_bayes classifier
# data.target is an array containing integers from `0-19` for each class of news group.

clf = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(email_data, data.target)

# Now test the classifier with a test sample.
test = ["Iam having a great day, my Ducati 6700, with 3-stroke engine is roaring."]
test_vector = tfidf.transform(test)
out = clf.predict(test_vector)
print(f'Out={out}')
print(f'Test sample belongs to Class={data.target_names[out[0]]}')

# Output
Out=array([8])
Test sample belongs to Class=rec.motorcycles
```

I didn't split the data into train and test, but just tried to show you how the basic implementation looks like. Also, you don't need to use `2 neurons` in `layers.Dense(2)` since you are anyway trying to find whether the email is just `ham or spam`. So `layers.Dense(1), activation="sigmiod"` with `loss=binaryCrossentropy` would suffice.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has really helped me. I changed my y_test and y_train to binary with your code. 

For the tf-idf I fitted it with the train emails, but also had to add `.ravel()` to the X_train variable as it was `(40, 1)` and tfidf needed `(40,)`. 

Then, once I did that, I printed the shape and got `(28, 1885)` which seems huge (the 1885). Anyhow, I defined the model with: `gnb = GaussianNB()` and when I try fitting it: `gnb.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train, order='C'))` I got a error that says: `A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required`.

Comment: Assuming your `X_train`  of `shape=(28.1885)` is the result after fitting the `tfidf vectorizer`, what you can do to convert the sparse array to dense is...use either `X_train.toarray()` or `X_train.todense()` and then fit the `guassianNB()`.